# Пропал звук в Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

Не знаю насколько корректно задавать тут такие вопросы, но больше некуда писать. Вчера всё работало. Я писал код, смотрел ютуб. Больше ничего не делал. Ничего не обновлял и не трогал никакие системные конфиги. После этого выключил ubuntu и перезагрузился на винду (2 системы на одном диске, почти год всё работало, проблем не возникало). На винде тоже всё работало и никаких проблем не было. Сегодня запускаю ubuntu и у меня куда-то пропал звук. Вот так выглядит настройка громкости (я могу двигать эти ползунки, но ничего не меняется):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядят настройки звука, нет ни 1 доступного устройства (должно быть минимум 2):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезагрузился на винду, там всё работает корректно и никаких проблем нет. Кроме пропажи звука заметил ещё 1 проблему. Стали очень долго открываться системные приложения (секунд 10-20 и при этом несколько раз появляется окошко о том, что приложение не отвечает). Так происходит с терминалом и настройками. Сторонние приложения типа браузера, редактора кода, телеграма открываются мгновенно. Не понимаю что произошло, есть идеи как это пофиксисть?

**Upd:** Открыл `alsamixer`, там почему-то отображается 3 звуковых карты, хотя у меня всего 1 в материнке. Так ощущение, что надо переключить на другую "звуковую карту". Вот так выглядит при "звуковой карте", которая сейчас установлена:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6 непонятных устройств, которые не настраиваются. Переключаю на другую "звуковую карту":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но оно не хочет сохраняться. Я выхожу и всё что я изменил сбрасывается. Пробовал через sudo и от рута, эффект тот же.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте обновить alsa - https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/alsa

Comment: @DenisE обновил, это не помогло, но заметил кое-что, обновил вопрос

Comment: Теперь попробуйте - https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: @DenisE Спасибо за попытки помочь, я нашёл решение и добавил его в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла эта команда:

```
killall pulseaudio; pulseaudio -k; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

Которую я нашёл в этой статье:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure